# Can hx-trigger happen in less than a second? E.g. hx-trigger="every 0.1s"

Tags: htmx

I want to do something like

```
<div hx-get="/latest_updates" hx-trigger="every 0.1s">
  Nothing Yet!
</div>
```

Is this possible with HTMX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ms` instead of `s` for sub-second triggers. E.g.

```
<div hx-get="/latest_updates" hx-trigger="every 100ms">
  Nothing Yet!
</div>
```

### Note

Polling every 100ms is unusual and you would probably look at SSE or WebSockets for something updated that frequently